# Adding Xilinx AXI DMA core to block design cause Xilinx SDK error

Tags: sdk, hardware, xilinx, zynq, vivado

After adding Xilinx AXI DMA IP Core to Block design (Vivado IP Integrator, Zynq), hardware specification, generated by Vivado become not processable by Xilinx SDK.

AXI DMA has simple configuration, read channel only, no Scatter/Gather.

Vivado 2014.1 / Xilinx SDK 2014.1

```
ERROR    :  [Common 17-55] 'get_property' expects at least one object.
ERROR: [Hsm 55-1545] Problem running tcl command ::sw_petalinux_v2_00_b::generate : ERROR: [Common 17-55] 'get_property' expects at least one object.

    while executing
"get_property NAME $axidma_ip_handle"
    ("axi_dma" arm line 8)
    invoked from within
"switch -exact $type {
        "axi_intc" {
            # Interrupt controllers
            lappend node [gen_intc $slave $intc "interrupt-controller" "C_NUM_INTR_INPUTS C_KIN..."
    (procedure "gener_slave" line 37)
    invoked from within
"gener_slave $bus_node $ip $intc_handle "" $busif_handle"
    ("foreach" body line 17)
    invoked from within
"foreach ip $sorted_ip {
        # make sure the sorted_ip list does not content force ip list
        # otherwise, same duplication of dts node will appeare..."
    (procedure "bus_bridge" line 153)
    invoked from within
"bus_bridge $hwproc_handle $intc 0 "M_AXI_DP" "" $ips "ps7_pl310 ps7_xadc""
    (procedure "generate_device_tree" line 93)
    invoked from within
"generate_device_tree "xilinx.dts" $bootargs $consoleip"
    (procedure "device-tree_v1_01_b::generate" line 53)
    invoked from within
"${bsp}::generate $os_handle"
    (procedure "namespace_generate" line 6)
    invoked from within
"namespace_generate $bsp $bsp $path $os_handle"
    ("foreach" body line 3)
    invoked from within
"foreach bsp ${bsps} {
        create_namespace $path $bsp $os_handle
        namespace_generate $bsp $bsp $path $os_handle
    }"
    (procedure "::sw_petalinux_v2_00_b::generate" line 16)
    invoked from within
"::sw_petalinux_v2_00_b::generate petalinux"
ERROR: [Hsm 55-1442] Error(s) while running TCL procedure generate()

ERROR    : Error generating bsp sources: Failed to generate BSP.
```

But without AXI DMA, the ARM+FPGA project works well.

Comment: Try updating your tool chain to 2014.4. 2014.1 is known to be buggy.

Comment: We have experienced problems with 2014.4 too, but the decision was found. We use SD card only, not QSPI. But switching off QSPI in Zynq properties (in IP Integrator) cause hardware spec (.hdf file) to be failed. I have spent half a day finding difference between my design that fails and example design that works fine, and the only difference that lead to fail is QSPI. It should be switched on in Zynq properties despite of it is not used.